# Synonymize [integration-tests] to [integration-testing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tag [integration-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-testing) has currently 3136 questions in it, and a fairly decent tag wiki.

The tag [integration-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-tests) has currently only 68 questions, and no tag wiki.

Both tags mean the same.

I hereby propose to synonymize [integration-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-tests) to [integration-testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integration-testing).

Comment: I think that we are over the 6 to 8 weeks here, any progress?

Comment: @BhargavRao so?